# Bing Map v7 to v8 migration

Tags: javascript, migration, bing-maps

I am working on a project to migrate bing map from version7( v7)  to v8 and following the procedure mentioned in the document

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx

Our bing map application (v7) is using getTargetBounds() method in map class  (as per below code) to navigate the map to show the location selected. As per the document (above link), this method has been depricated in the v8. Could you please advise what would be the work around to achieve this in bing map v8?

```
var targetBounds = bingMap.getTargetBounds();
                        var isView = targetBounds.contains(newLocaton);

                        if (!isView) {
                            bingMap.setView({ center: newLocaton });
                        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply use map.getBounds() after the view has changed.

Comment: Any work around for beforeStepRender,beforeSummaryRender,afterWaypointRender methods  in DirectionManager Events class as these methods have been depriciated?